# Parse ~4k files for a string (sophisticated conditions)

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing

### Problem description

There is a set of ~4000 python files with the following struture:

```
@ScriptInfo(number=3254,
            attibute=some_value,
            title="crawler for my website",
            some_other_key=some_value)

scenario_name = entity.get_script_by_title(title)
```

### The goal

The goal is to get the value of the title from the *ScriptInfo* decorator (in this case it is "crawler for my website"), but there are a couple of problems:

1) There is no rule for naming a variable that contains the title. That's why it can be title_name, my_title, etc. See example:

```
@ScriptInfo(number=3254,
            attibute=some_value,
            my_title="crawler for my website",
            some_other_key=some_value)

scenario_name = entity.get_script_by_title(my_title)
```

2) The @ScriptInfo decorator may have more than two arguments so getting its contents from between the parentheses in order to get the second parameter's value is not an option

### My (very naive) solution

But the piece of code that stays unchanged is the `scenario_name = entity.get_script_by_title(my_title)` line. Taking this into account, I've come up with the solution:

```
import re
title_variable_re = r"scenario_name\s?=\s?entity\.get_script_by_title\((.*)\)"
with open("python_file.py") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match(regexp, line):
            title_variable = re.match(title_variable_re, line).group(1)
title_re = title_variable  + r"\s?=\s\"(.*)\"?"
with open("python_file.py") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match(title_re, line):
            title_value = re.match(regexp, line).group(1)
print title_value
```

This snippet of code does the following:

1) Traverses (see the first `with open`) the script file and gets the variable with `title` value because it is up to a programmer to choose its name
2) Traverses the script file *again* (see the second `with open`) and gets the title's value

### The question for the stackoverflow family

Is there a better and more efficient way to get the title's (`my_title`'s, `title_name`'s, etc) value than traversing the script file two times?

Comment: For a start, you could break out of your loops once you've found a match. Unless you're expecting multiple matches, where matches later in the file should overwrite matches earlier in the file.

Comment: Are there more than one `@ScriptInfo ... scenario_name = ...` pairs per file? If so, are they always in order (i.e. does `scenario_name` always follow the `@ScriptInfo...` structure)? Finally, do your files have anything else apart from these two structures?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the file only once and save all lines into `fileContent`, add `break` where appropriate, and reuse the matches to access the captured `group`s, you obtain something like this (with parentheses after `print` for 3.x, without for 2.7):

```
import re

title_value = None 

title_variable_re = r"scenario_name\s?=\s?entity\.get_script_by_title\((.*)\)"
with open("scenarioName.txt") as file:
    fileContent = list(file.read().split('\n'))
    title_variable = None
    for line in fileContent:
        m1 = re.match(title_variable_re, line)
        if m1:
            title_variable = m1.group(1)
            break
    title_re = r'\s*' + title_variable  + r'\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"[,)]?\s*'
    for line in fileContent:
        m2 = re.match(title_re, line)
        if m2:
            title_value = m2.group(1)
            break
print(title_value)
```

Here an unsorted list of changes in the regular expressions:

- Allow space before the `title_variable`, that's what the `r'\s*' +` is for
- Allow space around `=`
- Allow comma or closing round paren in the end of the line in `title_re`, that's what the `[,)]?` is for
- Allow some space in the end of the line

When tested on the following file as input:

```
@ScriptInfo(number=3254,
        attibute=some_value,
        my_title="crawler for my website",
        some_other_key=some_value)

scenario_name = entity.get_script_by_title(my_title)
```

it produces the following output:

```
crawler for my website
```